# Get record between two date from multiple tables in SQL server

Tags: sql-server

I am looking to get records from following two tables

if there does not exist a record in Eligibility for the Participant SSN and EIN in the Transaction where ServiceDate of Transaction is within  BenefitEffectiveDate and GracePeriodEndDate.

there can be multiple  records for same participant in eligibility table with different plan period for a given Participant SSN and EIN .

for example in below script there are two records for participantSSN = 645075498 in eligibility table and both record has different BenefitEffectiveDate and GracePeriodEndDate, from this table we have to take minimum BenefitEffectiveDate and maximum GracePeriodEndDate. that means for this participant minimum date is 2015-01-01 and maximum date is 2018-01-01

Now in transaction table I have same participantSSN = 645075498 which has has transaction date is 2016-02-10 which is fall between minimum BenefitEffectiveDate and maximum GracePeriodEndDate in eligibility table for participantSSN = 645075498

I want to get record in my output for participantSSN = 645075498

How can I achieve it? so far I have written below query which is not giving me participantSSN = 645075498 in output result.

This is my expected result

```
| Tid |  TPAId  |  EIN  | ParticipantSSN | ParticipantFirstName | ParticipantLastName | TPAParentTransactionId | TPATransactionId | ServiceDate | TransactionDate | Amt |

| 118 | PayFlex | 54401 |      852258852 | GABRIEL              | BRYANT              |               45758201 |         55277801 | 2016-01-01  | 2016-01-02      |  15 |
| 124 | PayFlex | 54407 |      420145857 | CAROLYN              | WOMAC               |               45758207 |         55277807 | 2016-03-15  | 2016-03-15      |  60 |
| 125 | PayFlex | 54408 |      345658570 | THOMAS               | FAVELA              |               45758208 |         55277808 | 2016-03-16  | 2016-03-18      |  60 |
| 126 | PayFlex | 54409 |      541575015 | BETTY                | DAVIS               |               45758209 |         55277809 | 2016-03-17  | 2016-03-20      |  60 |
| 127 | PayFlex | 54410 |      541575015 | BETTY                | DAVIS               |               45758209 |         55277809 | 2016-03-17  | 2016-03-20      |  60 |
| 128 | PayFlex | 54409 |      541575015 | BETTY                | DAVIS               |               45758210 |         55277809 | 2016-03-17  | 2016-03-20      |  60 |
| 129 | PayFlex | 54409 |      541575016 | MANDY                | THOMPSON            |               45758211 |         55277810 | 2016-03-18  | 2016-03-20      |  80 |
| 130 | PayFlex | 54409 |      541575018 | FRANCIS              | GRAYER              |               45758212 |         55277811 | 2016-03-19  | 2016-03-22      |  79 |
| 122 | PayFlex | 54405 |      645075498 | MARY                 | WILSON              |               45758205 |         55277805 | 2016-02-07  | 2016-02-10      | 100 |
```

My Current SQL query

```
SELECT ParticipantFirstName, ServiceDate, *
FROM DebitCardTransaction d
WHERE   NOT EXISTS
(
   SELECT 1
   FROM Eligibility e
   WHERE e.TPAId = d.TPAId
      AND e.EIN = d.EIN
      AND e.ParticipantSSN = d.ParticipantSSN
    AND d.ServiceDate BETWEEN BenefitEffectiveDate AND GracePeriodEndDate
 )
```

Above it my current query and below is sample create table and insert sample data script

```
CREATE TABLE Eligibility(
EligibilityId        INTEGER  PRIMARY KEY 
,TPAId                VARCHAR(7)
,EIN                  INTEGER 
,SubscriberId         INTEGER 
,ParticipantFirstName  VARCHAR(9)
,ParticipantLastName   VARCHAR(9)
,ParticipantSSN        INTEGER 
,BenefitEffectiveDate DATE 
,GracePeriodEndDate   DATE 
);

INSERT INTO Eligibility(EligibilityId,TPAId,EIN,SubscriberId,ParticipantFirstName,ParticipantLastName,ParticipantSSN,BenefitEffectiveDate,GracePeriodEndDate) VALUES (227,'PayFlex',54406,15857506,'TIM','HOPE',138764141,'1/1/2016','2/2/2017');
INSERT INTO Eligibility(EligibilityId,TPAId,EIN,SubscriberId,ParticipantFirstName,ParticipantLastName,ParticipantSSN,BenefitEffectiveDate,GracePeriodEndDate) VALUES (228,'PayFlex',54401,15857501,'BRIEL','BRYANT',852258851,'1/1/2016','2/2/2017');
INSERT INTO Eligibility(EligibilityId,TPAId,EIN,SubscriberId,ParticipantFirstName,ParticipantLastName,ParticipantSSN,BenefitEffectiveDate,GracePeriodEndDate) VALUES (229,'PayFlex',54402,15857502,'LISA','PEREZ',292225757,'1/1/2016','2/2/2017');
INSERT INTO Eligibility(EligibilityId,TPAId,EIN,SubscriberId,ParticipantFirstName,ParticipantLastName,ParticipantSSN,BenefitEffectiveDate,GracePeriodEndDate) VALUES (230,'PayFlex',54403,15857503,'ALEXANDER','JEFFERSON',643035714,'1/1/2016','2/2/2017');
INSERT INTO Eligibility(EligibilityId,TPAId,EIN,SubscriberId,ParticipantFirstName,ParticipantLastName,ParticipantSSN,BenefitEffectiveDate,GracePeriodEndDate) VALUES (231,'PayFlex',54404,15857504,'SHIRLEY','PEREZ',458250578,'1/1/2016','2/2/2017');
INSERT INTO Eligibility(EligibilityId,TPAId,EIN,SubscriberId,ParticipantFirstName,ParticipantLastName,ParticipantSSN,BenefitEffectiveDate,GracePeriodEndDate) VALUES (232,'PayFlex',54405,15857505,'MARY','WILSON',645075498,'1/1/2015','2/2/2016');
INSERT INTO Eligibility(EligibilityId,TPAId,EIN,SubscriberId,ParticipantFirstName,ParticipantLastName,ParticipantSSN,BenefitEffectiveDate,GracePeriodEndDate) VALUES (233,'PayFlex',54405,15857505,'MARY','WILSON',645075498,'1/1/2016','2/2/2018');



CREATE TABLE DebitCardTransaction(
Tid                    INTEGER  PRIMARY KEY 
,TPAId                  VARCHAR(7)
,EIN                    INTEGER 
,ParticipantSSN         INTEGER 
,ParticipantFirstName   VARCHAR(9)
,ParticipantLastName    VARCHAR(9)
,TPAParentTransactionId INTEGER 
,TPATransactionId       INTEGER 
,ServiceDate            DATE 
,TransactionDate        DATE 
,Amt                    INTEGER 
);

INSERT INTO DebitCardTransaction(Tid,TPAId,EIN,ParticipantSSN,ParticipantFirstName,ParticipantLastName,TPAParentTransactionId,TPATransactionId,ServiceDate,TransactionDate,Amt) VALUES (118,'PayFlex',54401,852258852,'GABRIEL','BRYANT',45758201,55277801,'1/1/2016','1/2/2016',15);
 INSERT INTO DebitCardTransaction(Tid,TPAId,EIN,ParticipantSSN,ParticipantFirstName,ParticipantLastName,TPAParentTransactionId,TPATransactionId,ServiceDate,TransactionDate,Amt) VALUES (119,'PayFlex',54402,292225757,'LISA','PEREZ',45758202,55277802,'2/1/2016','2/2/2016',50);
INSERT INTO DebitCardTransaction(Tid,TPAId,EIN,ParticipantSSN,ParticipantFirstName,ParticipantLastName,TPAParentTransactionId,TPATransactionId,ServiceDate,TransactionDate,Amt) VALUES (120,'PayFlex',54403,643035714,'ALEXANDER','JEFFERSON',45758203,55277803,'2/2/2016','2/3/2016',50);
INSERT INTO DebitCardTransaction(Tid,TPAId,EIN,ParticipantSSN,ParticipantFirstName,ParticipantLastName,TPAParentTransactionId,TPATransactionId,ServiceDate,TransactionDate,Amt) VALUES (121,'PayFlex',54404,458250578,'SHIRLEY','PEREZ',45758204,55277804,'2/3/2016','2/5/2016',50);
INSERT INTO DebitCardTransaction(Tid,TPAId,EIN,ParticipantSSN,ParticipantFirstName,ParticipantLastName,TPAParentTransactionId,TPATransactionId,ServiceDate,TransactionDate,Amt) VALUES (122,'PayFlex',54405,645075498,'MARY','WILSON',45758205,55277805,'2/7/2016','2/10/2016',100);
INSERT INTO DebitCardTransaction(Tid,TPAId,EIN,ParticipantSSN,ParticipantFirstName,ParticipantLastName,TPAParentTransactionId,TPATransactionId,ServiceDate,TransactionDate,Amt) VALUES (123,'PayFlex',54406,138764141,'TIM','HOPE',45758206,55277806,'2/10/2016','2/11/2016',110);
INSERT INTO DebitCardTransaction(Tid,TPAId,EIN,ParticipantSSN,ParticipantFirstName,ParticipantLastName,TPAParentTransactionId,TPATransactionId,ServiceDate,TransactionDate,Amt) VALUES (124,'PayFlex',54407,420145857,'CAROLYN','WOMAC',45758207,55277807,'3/15/2016','3/15/2016',60);
INSERT INTO DebitCardTransaction(Tid,TPAId,EIN,ParticipantSSN,ParticipantFirstName,ParticipantLastName,TPAParentTransactionId,TPATransactionId,ServiceDate,TransactionDate,Amt) VALUES (125,'PayFlex',54408,345658570,'THOMAS','FAVELA',45758208,55277808,'3/16/2016','3/18/2016',60);
INSERT INTO DebitCardTransaction(Tid,TPAId,EIN,ParticipantSSN,ParticipantFirstName,ParticipantLastName,TPAParentTransactionId,TPATransactionId,ServiceDate,TransactionDate,Amt) VALUES (126,'PayFlex',54409,541575015,'BETTY','DAVIS',45758209,55277809,'3/17/2016','3/20/2016',60);
INSERT INTO DebitCardTransaction(Tid,TPAId,EIN,ParticipantSSN,ParticipantFirstName,ParticipantLastName,TPAParentTransactionId,TPATransactionId,ServiceDate,TransactionDate,Amt) VALUES (127,'PayFlex',54410,541575015,'BETTY','DAVIS',45758209,55277809,'3/17/2016','3/20/2016',60);
INSERT INTO DebitCardTransaction(Tid,TPAId,EIN,ParticipantSSN,ParticipantFirstName,ParticipantLastName,TPAParentTransactionId,TPATransactionId,ServiceDate,TransactionDate,Amt) VALUES (128,'PayFlex',54409,541575015,'BETTY','DAVIS',45758210,55277809,'3/17/2016','3/20/2016',60);
INSERT INTO DebitCardTransaction(Tid,TPAId,EIN,ParticipantSSN,ParticipantFirstName,ParticipantLastName,TPAParentTransactionId,TPATransactionId,ServiceDate,TransactionDate,Amt) VALUES (129,'PayFlex',54409,541575016,'MANDY','THOMPSON',45758211,55277810,'3/18/2016','3/20/2016',80);
INSERT INTO DebitCardTransaction(Tid,TPAId,EIN,ParticipantSSN,ParticipantFirstName,ParticipantLastName,TPAParentTransactionId,TPATransactionId,ServiceDate,TransactionDate,Amt) VALUES (130,'PayFlex',54409,541575018,'FRANCIS','GRAYER',45758212,55277811,'3/19/2016','3/22/2016',79);
```

Comment: Please post the expected results.

Comment: @FelixPamittan I have updated my expected result in my question

Comment: Why should Mary be in the result set? She does have a transaction between her minimum `BenefitEffectiveDate` and maximum `GracePeriodEndDate`.

Comment: @FelixPamittan In eligibility table mary has two records, now we have to select minimum BenefitEffectiveDate and maximum GracePeriodEndDate from these two records, that means we have minimum BenefitEffectiveDate  = 2015-01-01 and maximum GracePeriodEndDate is 2018-01-01, now if you look at transaction table for mary record it has serviceDate='2016-02-10' which is fall between above date range.

Comment: Correct. But you want: `if there does not exist a record in Eligibility for the Participant SSN and EIN in the Transaction where ServiceDate of Transaction is within BenefitEffectiveDate and GracePeriodEndDate.` So clearly, Mary fails this condition, since there exists a record.

Comment: @FelixPamittan you are right, she should not be included, let me check once again and let you know.

Comment: you should also replace the query inside the `NOT EXISTS` with this: `SELECT 1
  FROM Eligibility e
  WHERE 
   e.TPAId = d.TPAId
   AND e.EIN = d.EIN
   AND e.ParticipantSSN = d.ParticipantSSN   
  GROUP BY 
   e.ParticipantSSN
  HAVING
   d.ServiceDate BETWEEN MIN(BenefitEffectiveDate) AND MAX(GracePeriodEndDate)` to account muliple records in `Eligibility`.

Comment: @FelixPamittan yes this is what I was looking. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you're after;

```
SELECT
d.Tid
,d.TPAId
,d.EIN
,d.ParticipantSSN
,d.ParticipantFirstName
,d.ParticipantLastName
,d.TPAParentTransactionId
,d.TPATransactionId
FROM DebitCardTransaction d
LEFT JOIN (SELECT ParticipantSSN, MIN(BenefitEffectiveDate) BenefitEffectiveDate, MAX(GracePeriodEndDate) GracePeriodEndDate FROM #Eligibility GROUP BY ParticipantSSN) e
ON d.ParticipantSSN = e.ParticipantSSN
AND d.TransactionDate BETWEEN e.BenefitEffectiveDate AND e.GracePeriodEndDate
WHERE e.ParticipantSSN IS NULL OR d.ParticipantSSN = 645075498
ORDER BY d.Tid
```

It gives the result set that you've asked except for Tid 122 (Mary Wilson), which doesn't meet the criteria as I understand them.

Comment: Thanks for you answer but I want Mary Wilson to be included in my result set.

Comment: Why do you want Mary Wilson showing? you've surpressed everyone who has a TransactionDate between their BenefitEffectiveDate and their GracePeriodEndDate. I've udpated my answer which will get Mary's true Effective and Grace Period date but she's still going to be surpressed. What's special about Mary that she needs to be included?

Comment: I've just updated the where clause to force Mary into the result set, I'd still be interested to see why she needs to be included given the criteria

Comment: you are absolutely right, this is what I am looking. Thanks a lot for your quick help.

Comment: it's my mistake, just now I realize that mary should not be included.